# How to resurrect non-committed directory and files?

Tags: svn, command-line, restore, undelete

I managed to delete a folder from my working directory with command

```
svn delete MYDIR
```

I realized that the directory I deleted was a wrong one and I need to get it back. I can see the directory and all the subdirectories on my harddrive, but there are no files. If I check the status

```
svn status MYDIR
```

it shows all the files having the "D" mark before them. I haven't committed the changes yet, so is there a way to get those files back?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use

```
svn revert -R MYDIR
```

The `-R` is needed if there were any files previously in MYDIR as your `delete` command would have also tagged them as deleted.

Comment: Thanks. I just found this command too. Before I tried tons of google searches with 'undelete', 'restore' etc, but revert didn't come to my mind at all.

Answer (score 1):

Yes. Do a `svn revert` on the directory containing the deleted one.